# SPSS Rao-Scott chi-square when a cell is 0

Tags: spss, p-value, chi-squared, contingency

We are conducting a study in which we analyze data from a survey whith a complex sampling design. Therefore, to determine if there is an association or independence between categorical variables, we use the Rao-Scott chi-square provided by the complex samples module of SPSS.

As we understand, the Rao-Scott chi-square statistic cannot be calculated when there is a cell with a frequency equal to zero (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4567525/). And we have some contingency tables in which this case occurs and yet SPSS calculates a statistic and its associated p-value.

Would kindly inform us how is it possible for SPSS to calculate it? What adjustments are made to the calculation formula? What assumptions does it make?